# Bluetooth Logitech Ultrathin Touch Mouse won't connect (or disconnects after some time)

Tags: arch-linux, mouse, bluetooth

How can I connect my Bluetooth mouse? I've read https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/bluetooth_mouse. Still it doesn't work! (Argh) I do the following but it won't help. At first it did work but then it disconnected. I use KDE Plasma.

```
$ bluetoothctl 
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# connect 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 
Attempting to connect to 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Paired: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Class: 0x00000580
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Icon: input-mouse
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Connected: no
[bluetooth]# devices
Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Ultrathin Touch Mouse
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Connected: no
[bluetooth]# quit
[art@arch-pc ~]$ date -u +%V$(uname)|sha1sum|sed 's/\W//g' 
7d38bd8e0c1285adcc97eb67f504ec27ba689563
[art@arch-pc ~]$ date
Mon Aug 12 16:31:16 MSK 2019
[art@arch-pc ~]$ date -u
Mon Aug 12 13:31:43 UTC 2019
[art@arch-pc ~]$ date -u +%V$(uname)                      
33Linux
[art@arch-pc ~]$ date -u +%V$(uname)|sha1sum|sed 's/\W//g'
7d38bd8e0c1285adcc97eb67f504ec27ba689563
[art@arch-pc ~]$ bluetoothctl 
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power off 
Changing power off succeeded
[CHG] Controller 68:94:23:EC:BA:42 Powered: no
[CHG] Controller 68:94:23:EC:BA:42 Discovering: no
[CHG] Controller 68:94:23:EC:BA:42 Class: 0x00000000
[bluetooth]# power on
[CHG] Controller 68:94:23:EC:BA:42 Class: 0x0000010c
Changing power on succeeded
[CHG] Controller 68:94:23:EC:BA:42 Powered: yes
[bluetooth]# remove 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 
[DEL] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Ultrathin Touch Mouse
Device has been removed
[NEW] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Ultrathin Touch Mouse
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Connected: no
[DEL] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Ultrathin Touch Mouse
[NEW] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Ultrathin Touch Mouse
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Connected: no
[DEL] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Ultrathin Touch Mouse
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 68:94:23:EC:BA:42 Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device 5A:A9:2F:F2:A5:E9 5A-A9-2F-F2-A5-E9
[NEW] Device 64:C7:53:EA:7F:7B 64-C7-53-EA-7F-7B
[NEW] Device 42:B3:C9:72:36:25 42-B3-C9-72-36-25
[NEW] Device 7F:42:A3:01:6F:B7 7F-42-A3-01-6F-B7
[NEW] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Ultrathin Touch Mouse
[bluetooth]# trust 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Trusted: yes
Changing 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 trust succeeded
[bluetooth]# pair 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 
Attempting to pair with 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Connected: yes
[Ultrathin Touch Mouse]# connect 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 
Attempting to connect to 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.InProgress
[NEW] Device 4E:A3:77:47:23:19 4E-A3-77-47-23-19
[Ultrathin Touch Mouse]# connect 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 
Attempting to connect to 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.InProgress
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 RSSI: -56
[NEW] Device F8:2F:A8:C9:DE:86 BOLSHECO-YOTA
[CHG] Device F8:2F:A8:C9:DE:86 TxPower: 0
[Ultrathin Touch Mouse]# connect 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 
Attempting to connect to 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.InProgress
[CHG] Device 42:B3:C9:72:36:25 ManufacturerData Key: 0x004c
[CHG] Device 42:B3:C9:72:36:25 ManufacturerData Value:
  0c 0e 00 57 58 c2 65 bd 64 b2 bc bf fa 62 95 77  ...WX.e.d....b.w
[Ultrathin Touch Mouse]# connect 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 
Attempting to connect to 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.InProgress
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 RSSI: -47
[Ultrathin Touch Mouse]# unblock
Changing 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 unblock succeeded
[CHG] Device 42:B3:C9:72:36:25 RSSI: -60
[CHG] Device 42:B3:C9:72:36:25 ManufacturerData Key: 0x004c
[CHG] Device 42:B3:C9:72:36:25 ManufacturerData Value:
  0c 0e 00 59 58 8a 9b 95 8e 59 b2 57 d9 6d 17 42  ...YX....Y.W.m.B
[NEW] Device 62:6A:77:BD:4D:31 62-6A-77-BD-4D-31
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[NEW] Device 73:A0:6D:C1:AC:7F 73-A0-6D-C1-AC-7F
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 RSSI: -60
[CHG] Device 62:6A:77:BD:4D:31 RSSI: -68
[CHG] Device 42:B3:C9:72:36:25 RSSI: -71
[CHG] Device 42:B3:C9:72:36:25 ManufacturerData Key: 0x004c
[CHG] Device 42:B3:C9:72:36:25 ManufacturerData Value:
  0c 0e 00 5b 58 8d 9e 33 c3 85 64 c7 51 d0 51 b6  ...[X..3..d.Q.Q.
[NEW] Device 55:52:EA:D1:BC:B9 55-52-EA-D1-BC-B9
[NEW] Device 5F:03:B5:6B:7E:22 5F-03-B5-6B-7E-22
[NEW] Device 44:0B:60:9B:25:D5 44-0B-60-9B-25-D5
[CHG] Device 55:52:EA:D1:BC:B9 ManufacturerData Key: 0x004c
[CHG] Device 55:52:EA:D1:BC:B9 ManufacturerData Value:
  10 05 07 1c 05 d8 e8                             .......         
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 RSSI: -45
[bluetooth]# power off
Changing power off succeeded
[CHG] Device 44:0B:60:9B:25:D5 RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device 5F:03:B5:6B:7E:22 RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device 55:52:EA:D1:BC:B9 RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device 73:A0:6D:C1:AC:7F RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device 62:6A:77:BD:4D:31 RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device F8:2F:A8:C9:DE:86 TxPower is nil
[CHG] Device F8:2F:A8:C9:DE:86 RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device 4E:A3:77:47:23:19 RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device 7F:42:A3:01:6F:B7 RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device 42:B3:C9:72:36:25 RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device 64:C7:53:EA:7F:7B RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device 5A:A9:2F:F2:A5:E9 RSSI is nil
[CHG] Controller 68:94:23:EC:BA:42 Powered: no
[CHG] Controller 68:94:23:EC:BA:42 Discovering: no
[CHG] Controller 68:94:23:EC:BA:42 Class: 0x00000000
[bluetooth]# power on
[CHG] Controller 68:94:23:EC:BA:42 Class: 0x0000010c
Changing power on succeeded
[CHG] Controller 68:94:23:EC:BA:42 Powered: yes
[bluetooth]# pair-devices
Invalid command in menu main: pair-devices

Use "help" for a list of available commands in a menu.
Use "menu <submenu>" if you want to enter any submenu.
Use "back" if you want to return to menu main.
[bluetooth]# pair-device 
Invalid command in menu main: pair-device

Use "help" for a list of available commands in a menu.
Use "menu <submenu>" if you want to enter any submenu.
Use "back" if you want to return to menu main.
[bluetooth]# paired-devices 
Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Ultrathin Touch Mouse
[bluetooth]# connect 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 
Attempting to connect to 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Connected: no
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Class: 0x00000580
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Icon: input-mouse
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:95:E8:F7 Connected: yes
[Ultrathin Touch Mouse]# quit
[art@arch-pc ~]$ systemctl | grep bluetooth
sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1a.0-usb1-1\x2d1-1\x2d1.4-1\x2d1.4:1.0-bluetooth-hci0.device loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/bluetooth/hci0     
sys-subsystem-bluetooth-devices-hci0.device                                                 loaded active plugged   /sys/subsystem/bluetooth/devices/hci0                                            
bluetooth.service                                                                           loaded active running   Bluetooth service                                                                
bluetooth.target                                                                            loaded active active    Bluetooth                                                                        
[art@arch-pc ~]$ cat /etc/bluetooth/input.conf 
# Configuration file for the input service
# This section contains options which are not specific to any
# particular interface
[General]

# Set idle timeout (in minutes) before the connection will
# be disconnect (defaults to 0 for no timeout)
IdleTimeout=0

#Enable HID protocol handling in userspace input profile
#Defaults to false(hidp handled in hidp kernel module)
UserspaceHID=true

[art@arch-pc ~]$ pacman -Qs bluez-hid2hci
local/bluez-hid2hci 5.50-6
    Put HID proxying bluetooth HCI's into HCI mode
```

Comment: @StephenKitt Thanks for noting this. Done. Do you know why I have negative votes?

Comment: No, I don’t — but I do know you only have one. Have an upvote to balance it out, you’ve certainly done some research!

Comment: @StephenKitt Thanks for the vote! For some apps no mouse is really a frustration esp. when I don't have Touchpad configured correctly also. :(

Comment: I think you had negative votes because of the garbage in your log. What are all that "date" commands? You have to clean them before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And it was just discharged. The most obvious thing I didn't try!